# How to display data from multiple table using join

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

Experts,

Now i have added following code in **TabMasterController**

```
 private CAFMEntities db = new CAFMEntities();

        public ViewResult Index(string sortorder, int? pagesize, int? page)
        {
            int pageSize = pagesize ?? 10;
            if (Request.HttpMethod != "GET")
            {
                page = 1;
                pageSize = 10;
            }
            ViewBag.SelectedPageSize = pageSize;

            ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortorder;
            ViewBag.FirstNameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortorder) ? "FirstName desc" : "";
            ViewBag.LastNameSortParm = sortorder == "LastName" ? "LastName desc" : "LastName";
            ViewBag.DepNameSortParm = sortorder == "depName" ? "depName desc" : "depName";

            var joined = from tm in db.TabMasters
                         join tk in db.TabKeys on tm.colID equals tk.colID
                         join td in db.TabDeps on tk.depID equals td.depID
                         select new { tm.FirstName, tm.LastName, tk.colID, tk.depID, td.depName };
            switch (sortorder)
            {
                case "FirstName":
                    joined = joined.OrderBy(m => m.FirstName);
                    break;
                case "FirstName desc":
                    joined = joined.OrderByDescending(m => m.FirstName);
                    break;
                case "LastName":
                    joined = joined.OrderBy(m => m.LastName);
                    break;
                case "LastName desc":
                    joined = joined.OrderByDescending(m => m.LastName);
                    break;
                case "depName":
                    joined = joined.OrderBy(m => m.depName);
                    break;
                case "depName desc":
                    joined = joined.OrderByDescending(m => m.depName);
                    break;
                default:
                    joined = joined.OrderBy(m => m.FirstName);
                    break;
            }

            int pageIndex = (page ?? 1) - 1;
            int start = (pageIndex * pageSize);
            ViewBag.TotalRecord = joined.Count();
            ViewBag.StartRecord = start + 1;
            ViewBag.EndRecord = ((start + pageSize) >= ViewBag.TotalRecord) ? ViewBag.TotalRecord : (start + pageSize);
            return View(joined.ToPagedList(pageIndex, pageSize));
        }
```

**UPDATED**

```
namespace MVCMultilingual.Models
{
    public class TabMasterModel 
    {
        [ReadOnly(true)]
        public int colID { get; set; }
        [ReadOnly(true)]
        public int depID { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("FirstName")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("LastName")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("depName")]
        public string depName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<MVCMultilingual.Models.TabMasterModel>
```

but i dont know hot to set query output to the class

The following code of **Index** page of **TabMasterController**

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<MVCMultilingual.TabMaster>
@using Helper
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>
    Index</h2>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500">
    <tr class="row-head">
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("FirstName", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.FirstNameSortParm, pagesize = ViewBag.SelectedPageSize })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("LastName", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.LastNameSortParm, pagesize = ViewBag.SelectedPageSize })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("depName", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.DepNameSortParm, pagesize = ViewBag.SelectedPageSize })
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @{
        foreach (var row in Model.Select((item, index) => new { index, item }))
        {
        @Html.Raw(GridHelper.BeginRow(row.index));
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => row.item.FirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => row.item.LastName)
        </td>
         <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => row.item.depName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = row.item.colID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = row.item.colID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = row.item.colID })
        </td>
        @Html.Raw(GridHelper.EndRow());
        }
    }
    @Html.Raw(GridHelper.BeginFooter(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(), 3, Convert.ToInt16(ViewBag.StartRecord), Convert.ToInt16(ViewBag.EndRecord), Convert.ToInt16(ViewBag.TotalRecord), Convert.ToInt16(Model.PageCount), Convert.ToInt16(Model.PageNumber), Convert.ToInt16(ViewBag.SelectedPageSize), ViewBag.CurrentSort, Model.HasPreviousPage, Model.HasNextPage))
    @Html.Raw(GridHelper.EndFooter())
  </table>
```

in this code i have use following line

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<MVCMultilingual.TabMaster>
```

Now i would like to add TabDep.depName in this page but it will gives me an error

```
   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => row.item.depName)
```

**Error:**
'MVCMultilingual.TabMaster' does not contain a definition for 'depName' and no extension method 'depName' accepting a first argument of type 'MVCMultilingual.TabMaster' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: why i am taking -1? Please provide your reason!

Comment: +1 because I don't believe there's anything here to warrant a -1 plus you provided a pic.

Comment: Thanks Adam, but i am looking for a solution, please give me a solution if you have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for a start you need to have a check to make sure joined != 0, then you wont be trying to use the data when not created / I.E  no results from database.   You always have a sortorder so you will always go into the switch. last tabMaster is your model for TabMaster table, what you have created is a new model so you should actually be creating a ViewModel and populating the new View model with the data and then looping your records through the view model, you will find that this fixes the problem

```
select new MyViewModel{
     fname = tm.FirstName, 
     lname = tm.LastName, 
     ID = tk.colID, 
     DEP = tk.depID, 
     name = td.depName
 }
```

Comment: I have updated code as per your suggestion but i do not know how to integrate it on my code

Comment: same way as befor but you pass over the new Model  I.E  MyViewModel  and this is the model declared at the top of your view page

Answer (score 0):

Once you call this:

```
select new { tm.FirstName, tm.LastName, tk.colID, tk.depID, td.depName };
```

Your result is not `TabMaster` anymore. The result becomes anonymous type and everything expecting `TabMaster` will fail. So if you want to use a projection and work with it in strongly typed way you must project to a new type - something like TabMasterViewModel`.

Btw. Why do you have junction table mapped? Just remove `Id` in `TabKey` and make both `ColId` and `DepId` composite primary key and your model will simplify because you will have direct M:N relation between `TabMaster` and `TabDep`.